# SendKeys does not always send the key macros to AppActivate via ProcessId to another process

Tags: vba, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, sendkeys

**Task:** Write a program that simply displays 3 buttons when clicked on, which simulates pressing a key combination (macros Ctrl+Z) in another window.

**What I did:** My code:

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Dim FigmaWindowName As String
    Dim Processes

    Public Sub New()
        'init form
        InitializeComponent()

        'set top position
        TopMost = True


    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonUndo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonUndo.Click

        Processes = GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_Process")

        For Each Process In Processes
            If StrComp(Process.Name, "Figma.exe", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then

                ' Activate the window using its process ID...
                With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
                    .AppActivate(Process.ProcessId)
                    .SendKeys("(^z)")

                End With

                ' We found our process. No more iteration required...
                Exit For

            End If
        Next

        '....other buttons
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Problem:** not stable. If it doesn’t work, then both windows flicker when clicking and the key combination does not send to other app. https://www.loom.com/share/89c47dfa38bc4bb6b1d3ff8b97b84ac8

**Question** What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I don't believe that there exists a stable application that works with "send keys". But if it's the only way to do the automation here's some additional check for your code.

```
Dim wShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Dim isWindowActive As Boolean = False
Do 
    'AppActivate will return true when window is really active'
    isWindowActive = wShell.AppActivate(Process.ProcessId) 
    WScript.Sleep 100
Loop Until isWindowActive 
wShell.sendKeys("(^z)")
```

Comment: No, it's not the only way. But I don't know other way... Could you can describe other way or send example?

Comment: You can try to use AutoIt, works quite stable with send keys and simple to use. Or more complicated - if you are familiar with win API, you can try to solve your task with UIAutomationClient.

Comment: WOW I tried to use AutoItX3 end it works fine but I'm not sure if this code is correct (I say about Run after click): 

http://joxi.ru/KAxMgkzhZXX1dr

Comment: Sleep is not really neede for it. AutoIt should handle waitings. The rest looks fine.

Comment: And one more... Maby you know. This func  .Run() .WinWaitActive() of  AutoItX3 didn't work in x64 Windows and my app crashed. The path and name are correct. http://joxi.ru/KAxMgkzhZXXdOr maby you can help me last time

Comment: Sorry, that's not familiar to me. Good luck with investigating and debugging :)